# ¿como pasar los datos de un DataTable a una tabla en MySQL en c#?

Tags: mysql, c#, sql, datatable

actualmente estoy tratando de hacer que por medio de un botón se ejecute una query en una base de datos remota(escolar) y que al mismo tiempo con los datos guardados en el Data Table se guarden los mismos en mi tabla de base de datos local.

este es mi código de mi botón en c#:

```
 private void button1_Click_2(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // CADENA DE CONEXION A LA BASE DE DATOS
        string cadenaConexion = "Database=dprn3u3; Data source=35.197.23.46; User Id=estudiante; Password=dprn3pass; SSL Mode=None";
        MySqlConnection conexion, comando2,conexion3;
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        MySqlDataReader resultados;
        MySqlCommand comand = null;
        string cadena = "Database=vivero; Data source=localhost; User Id=root; Password=; SSL Mode=None";
        conexion3 = new MySqlConnection(cadena);

        try
        {
            // ESTABLECE LA CONEXION A LA BASE DE DATOS
            conexion = new MySqlConnection(cadenaConexion);
            comando2 = new MySqlConnection(cadenaConexion);

            // CONSULTA SQL
            MySqlCommand comandos = new MySqlCommand("SELECT planta, MONTH(fecha) AS mes, YEAR(fecha) AS year, SUM(cantidad) as cantidad, SUM(total) as total FROM ventas GROUP BY year,mes,planta;", conexion);
            MySqlCommand mysql = new MySqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ventas;", comando2);


            // DECIMOS EL TIPO DE CONSULTA 
            comandos.CommandType = CommandType.Text;


            // ABRE LA CONEXION A LA BASE DE DATOS
            conexion.Open();
            comando2.Open();
            conexion3.Open();

            // REALIZA LA CONSULTA Y LA ALMACENA EN LA VARIABLE RESULTADO
            resultados = comandos.ExecuteReader();



            // CARGA LOS REGISTROS OBTENIDOS EN LA TABLA Y EN EL STATUSTRIP 
            dt.Load(resultados);


            int contar = Convert.ToInt32(mysql.ExecuteScalar());
            etiquetavalores.Text = contar.ToString() + " " + "registros";

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }

        database.DataSource = dt;

        foreach (DataRow registro in dt.Rows)
        {
            string especie = (string)registro["planta"];
            int mesventa = (int)registro["mes"];
            int yearventa = (int)registro["year"];
            var cantidad = registro["cantidad"];
            var total = registro["total"];

            string consulta = string.Empty;

            consulta = "INSERT INTO ventas VALUES ('" + especie + "','" + mesventa + "','" + yearventa + "','" + cantidad + "','" + total + "')";


            comand = new MySqlCommand(consulta, new MySqlConnection("Database=vivero; Data source=localhost; User Id=root; Password=; SSL Mode=None"));

        }


    }
```

Esta es mi base de datos:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al momento de ejecutar el codigo si muestra los datos conforme a la Query que se le hae a la base de datos remota, pero al no guarda nada en mi base de datos local:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero puedan orientarme a saber cual es mi error y así mismo les agradezco de antemano su ayuda y su tiempo.

Comment: Agregale en un `try catch` la consulta y mira que te responde

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Por lo que veo es que no estas ejecutando el insert, en tu codigo:

```
    foreach (DataRow registro in dt.Rows)
    {
        string especie = (string)registro["planta"];
        int mesventa = (int)registro["mes"];
        int yearventa = (int)registro["year"];
        var cantidad = registro["cantidad"];
        var total = registro["total"];

        string consulta = string.Empty;

        consulta = "INSERT INTO ventas VALUES ('" + especie + "','" + mesventa + "','" + yearventa + "','" + cantidad + "','" + total + "')";


        comand = new MySqlCommand(consulta, new MySqlConnection("Database=vivero; Data source=localhost; User Id=root; Password=; SSL Mode=None"));
        **comand.ExecuteNonQuery();**

    }
```

Falta el **comando.ExecuteNonQuery();** que el lo que hace el insert a tu BD, sin embargo necesitas dale mas estructura a tu codigo.
En el evento de click al boton estas haciendo demasiadas cosas, eso no es una buena practica.
Veo que haces muchisimas conexiones a la base de datos y solo haces un insert, asi como veo que tienes en tu codigo los parametros a tu BD, eso es muy mala practica ya que si cambian la base de datos usuario o contraseña vas a tener que editar el codigo y complicar otra version.

Te dejo un ejemplo del insert:

```
private void button1_Click_2(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // CADENA DE CONEXION A LA BASE DE DATOS
    string cadenaConexion = "Database=dprn3u3; Data source=35.197.23.46; User Id=estudiante; Password=dprn3pass; SSL Mode=None";
    string cadena = "Database=vivero; Data source=localhost; User Id=root; Password=; SSL Mode=None";
    MySqlConnection conexion, comando2,conexion3;
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    MySqlDataReader resultados;
    MySqlCommand comand = null;

    try
    {
        // ESTABLECE LA CONEXION A LA BASE DE DATOS
        conexion = new MySqlConnection(cadenaConexion);
        comando2 = new MySqlConnection(cadenaConexion);

        // CONSULTA SQL
        MySqlCommand comandos = new MySqlCommand("SELECT planta, MONTH(fecha) AS mes, YEAR(fecha) AS year, SUM(cantidad) as cantidad, SUM(total) as total FROM ventas GROUP BY year,mes,planta;", conexion);
        MySqlCommand mysql = new MySqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ventas;", comando2);


        // DECIMOS EL TIPO DE CONSULTA 
        comandos.CommandType = CommandType.Text;


        // ABRE LA CONEXION A LA BASE DE DATOS
        conexion.Open();
        comando2.Open();

        // REALIZA LA CONSULTA Y LA ALMACENA EN LA VARIABLE RESULTADO
        resultados = comandos.ExecuteReader();



        // CARGA LOS REGISTROS OBTENIDOS EN LA TABLA Y EN EL STATUSTRIP 
        dt.Load(resultados);


        int contar = Convert.ToInt32(mysql.ExecuteScalar());
        etiquetavalores.Text = contar.ToString() + " " + "registros";

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }

    database.DataSource = dt;

    //Generamos un StringBuilder que contendra los valores a insertar
    StringBuilder _valoresParaInsertar = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (DataRow registro in dt.Rows)
    {
      if (_valoresParaInsertar.length() > 0)
          _valoresParaInsertar.Append(",")
      //Agregamos valores
        _valoresParaInsertar.Append($"('{(string)registro["planta"]}','{(int)registro["mes"]}','{(int)registro["year"]}','{registro["cantidad"]}','{registro["total"]}')");
    }
    //Hacemos la insercion
    int _registrosInsertados = InsertaDatos(_valoresParaInsertar.ToString());
    Console.WriteLine($"Se han insertado {_registrosInsertados} documentos");
}
```

La funcion para insertar:

```csharp
private int InsertaDatos(string valoresParaInsertar)
  {
    using (MySqlConnection conexion = MySqlConnection("Database=vivero; Data source=localhost; User Id=root; Password=; SSL Mode=None"))
    {
      conexion.Open();
      //Query de insert
      comand = new MySqlCommand($"INSERT INTO ventas VALUES {valoresParaInsertar};", conexion);
      int _registrosGuardados = comand.ExecuteNonQuery();
      return _registrosGuardados;
    }
  }
```

Comment: muchas gracias, me ayudo bastante la explicación al final hice el insert  añadiendo columna por columna en un foreach con ExecuteNonQuery()